# SQL group by time interval plus variable name using Python

Tags: python, sqlite, time

I have two data frames, A and B, with the following information:

Date frame A with 4 variables:
name, start_date, end_date, ID

A.ID is a concatenation of name and start_date.

Date frame B with 5 variables:
name, date, parameter, value

My goal is to aggregate by mean the value by: the B.date should be between A.start_date and A.end_date and the A.name should be equals to B.name. Please take care that the name can be repeated more than one time in the data frame A. Date is a continuos time. For example from start_date to end_date by step of 1 hour.

```
   SELECT A.ID, A.name,  B.parameter, AVG(value)
   FROM A
   JOIN B ON A.name = B.name
   GROUP BY parameter
   WHERE start_date < date < end_date
```

```
A = {'name': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c'], 
     'start_date': ['01-01-2020', '01-01-2020', '10-01-2020', '15-01-2020'], 
     "end_date": ['05-01-2020', '06-01-2020', '15-01-2020', '20-01-2020'],
     'ID': ['a_01-01-2020', 'b_01-01-2020', 'a_10-01-2020', 'c_15-01-2020']}
```

```
B = {'name': ['a','a','b','b','a','a','c','c'], 
     'date': ['01-01-2020:00','01-01-2020:01', '01-01-2020:05','01-01-2020:06', '10-01-2020:12', '10-01-2020:13', '15-01-2020:00', '15-01-2020:01' ],
     'parameter': ['dog','dog','dog','dog','dog','dog','dog','cat'],
      'value': [10,20,20,30,1000,2000,50,100]}
```

The final data frame should be:

```
C = {'ID': ['a_01-01-2020', 'b_01-01-2020', 'a_10-01-2020', 'c_15-01-2020','c_15-01-2020'],
    'name': ['a','b','a','c','c],
    'parameter': ['dog','dog','dog','dog','cat'],
    'value': [15,25,1500,50,100]}
```

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: I did it, thank you for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause must be put before the `GROUP BY`. Also, I think the date check should be fixed as follows:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.name,  B.parameter, AVG(value)
FROM A
JOIN B ON A.name = B.name
WHERE start_date < date AND date < end_date
GROUP BY parameter
```